# Re-map or un-map F10 from triggering window file menu in Xfce

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xubuntu, settings

By default F10 on Xfce activates the window File menu and so cannot be used as a shortcut in any program.

I already looked in the Window Manager and Keyboard settings pages and no F10 key binding is listed.

How can I re-map/un-map this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xfce provides a way to disable the key binding from the **Settings Editor**.

This will work only for GTK+ 2 applications, given that ["gtk-menu-bar-accel" has been deprecated in GTK+ 3 (since version 3.10)](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-menu-bar-accel). As a result, user might have no choice but to disable the key binding per application, which may also depend on which toolkit in use.

Go to **Applications Menu > Settings > Settings Editor**. Xfce 4.10 or newer provides another way to access by **Settings Manager > Other - Settings Editor**.

In the Settings Editor:

- On the left, under "Channel", scroll down and select "xsettings"
- On the right, under "Property | Type | Locked | Value", look for **Gtk > MenuBarAccel**
- Double-click on the row of "MenuBarAccel" to edit this property
- In the "Edit Property" dialog, delete the value `F10` (leave it blank) and click `Save`.

The final step will disable the key binding for activating the menu bar.

**Custom keys**: User can also change the key binding to something else. For example, changing the value to `<Control>F12` will re-map to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> key combination to activate the menu. Try with any key bindings using `<Alt>` `<Shift>` and other keys. More clues are found under "Channel: xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts" and under "Property".

**Restore to default**: In the Settings Editor, click **Reset** button that is located at the right-most icon, either at near-bottom of window (Xfce 4.10 or newer) or, on top of "Property" column (Xfce 4.8).

**Precaution (Xfce 4.8)**: In older Xfce, clicking **Reset** button will cause the entire row of "MenuBarAccel" to be removed at all. To avoid this, double-click on the row again and change the value to `F10` to restore.

> Name: `/Gtk/MenuBarAccel`
> Type: `String`
> Value: `F10`

In case user have accidentally deleted the property, create again the property as follows. Click **New** and re-register the property in the "New Property" dialog with the settings quoted as above.

Xfce can still disable the key binding for GTK+ 2 applications, such as Orage and Xournal. Given that many applications are now GTK+ 3, the setting will be less and less relevent in newer Xfce.

Comment: I have changed the value, but `F10` is still working. I have to log out and in at least for changes to be applied, I guess, right?

Comment: For xfce4-terminal, you need to disable F10 in the program Preferences (see answer below) even if you've disabled F10 globally in the Settings Editor as described here.

Answer (score 11):

There is also a setting for disabling this shortcut on `Terminal Preferences -> Advanced`:

[image]

Comment: Should be accepted answer.

Comment: This only works on xfce4-terminal, not on other programs.