# How to fix the search box grayed out xfce settings editor?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, xfce4-terminal

The list of settings is very big and I definitely cannot search everything by eye. I would like to find the application which is using the `F10` key to fix this issue: [Re-map or un-map F10 from triggering window file menu in Xfce](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181864/re-map-or-un-map-f10-from-triggering-window-file-menu-in-xfce)

As you can see, the `Search Box` is grayed out and I cannot type anything on it. I use `Linux Mint Xfce 19.1`

[image]

How I can search into the contents of the `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts` for the application using the `F10` key? (The list is very big, so no exhaustive search)

Comment: just a shot in the dark ..... try clicking on different rows in the right side pane ..... also try clicking on the left pane